# Misplacing theorem header when followed by a prooftree

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, newtheorem, bussproofs

When I put a prooftree immediately after \begin{solution} it places the header of the solution environment neither aligned to the left or above the prooftree. When there is some text preceeding the \begin{prooftree} it comes out fine but since I'm writing a lot of exercises and solutions this seems like a very repetitive solution.

It looks like this

[image]

I want it to look like the second example except not requiring there to be text.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove= 6pt,
  spacebelow= 6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont \itshape,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=1em,
  qed= \qedsymbol
]{solution}
\declaretheorem[style=solution, numbered = no]{Solution}

\begin{document}

text text text text
\begin{Solution}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$[P]^{1}$}
\AxiomC{$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\wedge E$}
\UnaryInfC{$P \rightarrow Q$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow E$}
\BinaryInfC{$Q$}
\AxiomC{$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\wedge E$}
\UnaryInfC{$Q \rightarrow R$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow E$}
\BinaryInfC{$R$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow I_{1}$}
\UnaryInfC{$P \rightarrow R$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{Solution}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `\mbox{}` after `\begin{solution}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove= 6pt,
  spacebelow= 6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont \itshape,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=1em,
  qed= \qedsymbol
]{solution}
\declaretheorem[style=solution, numbered = no]{Solution}

\begin{document}

text text text text
\begin{Solution}
\mbox{}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$[P]^{1}$}
\AxiomC{$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\wedge E$}
\UnaryInfC{$P \rightarrow Q$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow E$}
\BinaryInfC{$Q$}
\AxiomC{$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\wedge E$}
\UnaryInfC{$Q \rightarrow R$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow E$}
\BinaryInfC{$R$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize $\rightarrow I_{1}$}
\UnaryInfC{$P \rightarrow R$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{Solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]